# Get multiple keys from json in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have the following json structure in a file:

```
[
{ "Date": "timevalue", "Org": "b4256282", "Referer": "somevalue" },
{ "Date": "timevalue", "Org": "b4257482", "Referer": "somevalue" },
{ "Date": "timevalue", "Org": "b4253345", "Referer": "somevalue" },
....
]
```

I want to extract all the Org's.

My code is:

```
import json

jdata = json.loads(str_of_above_json)
for orgs in jdata['Org']:
     print(orgs)
```

However this code does not work ... I get the following error messag

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `for orgs in jdata:
     print(orgs['Org'])`

Comment: Remember, your data once loaded in as a Python structure is going to be a list of dictionaries. Keyword here is a *list*. So, Your for loop is just going to iterate over a list, and then each `orgs` will be the dictionary, which *then* you can access the 'Org' key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over each dictionary in the list and then index dict in turn with dict indexing. For each dictionary in the list,

1. get the i<sup>*th*</sup> dictionary
2. get the value associated with `Org` in the i<sup>*th*</sup> dictionary
3. print said value from (2)

In code, this is

```
for dict_ in jdata:
    org = dict_['Org']
    print(org)
```

However, we have the power of list comprehension at our disposal, so the code above can more succinctly be represented by,

```
jdata = json.loads(str_of_above_json)
orgs = [x['Org'] for x in jdata]      
print(orgs)
```

**Why isn't your current code working?**
You do `jdata['Org']`, but `[...]` is a dict indexing operation, and this will throw errors because `jdata` is a *list*.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, your data once loaded in as a Python structure is going to be a list of dictionaries. To keep it simple, it's just:

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

Keyword here is a *list*. So, your for loop will/should iterate over a *list*, giving you each dictionary at every iteration.

At this point you can then access the 'Org' key.

So when you do:

```
for orgs in jdata:
    print(orgs) # each dictionary
```

At that point, you can *now* access the `Org` key in the dictionary:

```
for orgs in jdata:
    print(orgs) # each dictionary
    print(orgs['Org']) # The value of 'Org' in each dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

jdata = json.loads(str_of_above_json)
for orgs in jdata:
    print(orgs["Org"])
```

You need to iterate over the list []
then print the "org" part of each data.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are correct and will solve your current problem.

But if you manipulate a lot with structures like this, you might find the package [`plucky`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plucky/) helpful (full disclosure: I'm the author of that package).

For example (assuming your `jdata` is loaded):

```
>>> import plucky
>>> plucky.plucks(data, '.Org')
['b4256282', 'b4257482', 'b4253345']
```

or:

```
>>> plucky.pluckable(data).Org
['b4256282', 'b4257482', 'b4253345']
```