# Parse JSON data with varying parent keys using python

Tags: python, json

Here is my working example

```
jsonData = {
    "3": {
        "map_id": "1",
        "marker_id": "3",
        "title": "Your title here",
        "address": "456 Example Ave",
        "desc": "Description",
        "pic": "",
        "icon": "",
        "linkd": "",
        "lat": "3.14",
        "lng": "-22.98",
        "anim": "0",
        "retina": "0",
        "category": "1",
        "infoopen": "0",
        "other_data": ["0"]
    },
    "4": {
        "map_id": "1",
        "marker_id": "4",
        "title": "Title of Place",
        "address": "123 Main St, City, State",
        "desc": "insert description",
        "pic": "",
        "icon": "",
        "linkd": "",
        "lat": "1.23",
        "lng": "-4.56",
        "anim": "0",
        "retina": "0",
        "category": "0",
        "infoopen": "0",
        "other_data": ["0"]
    }
```

I am having such a hard time getting the `title` and `address` keys. Here is what I have tried:

```
for each in testJson:
    print(each["title"])
```

and I get the following error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. I don't understand why this isn't working.

I have tried so many variations to get the key data, but I just can't get it to work. I can't really change the raw JSON either because my real JSON data is a huge file. I have looked on stackoverflow for a similarly formatted JSON example (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334930/get-multiple-keys-from-json-in-python)) but have come up short. I assume there is something wrong with the way my JSON is formatted, because I have parsed JSON before with the above code without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting that error because your looping over the *keys*, which don't have `title` and `address` properties. Those properties exist in the inner dictionaries, which are the *values* of the dictionary.

Here is how you can iterate over the [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) instead:

```
for value in jsonData.values():
    print(value["title"], value["address"])
```

Which will give you the title and address:

```
Your title here 456 Example Ave
Title of Place 123 Main St, City, State
```

If you want to find out which *key* your iterating over, you can loop over the tuple `(key, value)` pair from [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for key, value in jsonData.items():
    print(f"key = {key}, title = {value['title']}, address = {value['address']}")
```

Which will show the key with the address and title:

```
key = 3, title = Your title here, address = 456 Example Ave
key = 4, title = Title of Place, address = 123 Main St, City, State
```

Comment: Thanks @RoadRunner, it works! I hadn't seen the ```.values()``` used this way with JSON data, and your explanation makes good sense. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`for… in` loops iterate over the *keys* of dictionaries, not their values.  If you want to iterate over their values, you can either use `.values()`:

```
for value in someDict.values():
```

…or you can iterate over `items()`, which will give you the key and the value as a tuple:

```
for key, value in someDict.items():
```

The reason why you are getting the error message you are is because when you try to get `title` out of `each`, `each` is actually the key, .i.e. `"3"` or `"4"`.  Python will let you get individual characters out of a string with things like `someString[0]` to get the first character, but it doesn't make sense to access things like `someString['title']`.